# Filter properties from an array based on another array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of objects like this:

```
var bridges = {"countyCd:15
createdDate:"0001-01-01T00:00:00"
createdUserId:0
createdUserIdZ:null
createdUserName:null
description:"SR 1@.-CENTRAL RR COMP OF IND"
districtId:null
encryptedId1:null
encryptedId2:null
isDirty:false
modelState:null
nbiNumber:10
routeNbr:"1"
routeTypeCd:"SR"
transactionType:null
updatedDate:"0001-01-01T00:00:00"
updatedUserId:0
updatedUserIdZ:null
updatedUserName:null", [...]....}
```

I have another array like this

```
[countyCd, nbiNumber]
```

How can create another array keeping just two properties so it becomes like

bridges = {"countyCd:15
        nbiNumber:10"
       , [...]....}

Basically, I am looking for a way to create a function that takes a data array and a filter array as parameters and filters the data array based on the filter array.

Any pointers to this will be much appreciated.

Comment: Is `bridges` actually an array, or is it an object like you posted? The solution would be different based on which it is

Comment: @RobM.Bridges is an Array of objects. I am sorry about the ambiguity in my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One solution would be to `map` over each record and `reduce` your filter array into an object containing the target proprties:

```
var bridges = [{
    countyCd:15,
    createdDate:"0001-01-01T00:00:00",
    createdUserId:0,
    createdUserIdZ:null,
    createdUserName:null,
    description:"SR 1@.-CENTRAL RR COMP OF IND",
    districtId:null,
    encryptedId1:null,
    encryptedId2:null,
    isDirty:false,
    modelState:null,
    nbiNumber:10,
    routeNbr:"1",
    routeTypeCd:"SR",
    transactionType:null,
    updatedDate:"0001-01-01T00:00:00",
    updatedUserId:0,
    updatedUserIdZ:null,
    updatedUserName:null
}, {
    countyCd:23,
    createdDate:"0001-01-01T00:00:00",
    createdUserId:0,
    createdUserIdZ:null,
    createdUserName:null,
    description:"SR 1@.-CENTRAL RR COMP OF IND",
    districtId:null,
    encryptedId1:null,
    encryptedId2:null,
    isDirty:false,
    modelState:null,
    nbiNumber:10,
    routeNbr:"1",
    routeTypeCd:"SR",
    transactionType:null,
    updatedDate:"0001-01-01T00:00:00",
    updatedUserId:0,
    updatedUserIdZ:null,
    updatedUserName:null
}];

var filters = ['countyCd', 'nbiNumber'];
var transformedRecords = bridges.map(bridge => filters.reduce((p, c) => { 
    p[c] = bridge[c];
    return p; 
}, {}));
console.log(transformedRecords);
```

Answer (score 1):

Say you have an array of `bridges`, call it `bA`:

```
var bA = []; //bridges array
var nbiA = []; // nbia array with countyCd
var newA = []; // new array
bA.forEach(function(element, index, array){
    var newEntry = {
        'countyCd':element.countyCd,
        'nbiNumber':nbiA.find(function(nbi){
            return nbi[countyCd] == element.countyCd;
        }).nbiNumber
    };
    newA.push(newEntry);
});
//do whatever you want with the newA array
```